# Author attribution

Tags: discussion

I was pretty active on here a few months ago but I got distracted by the venture of building a free music/education site.

I would love to return to this forum and get active again, as I enjoyed it and some of my answers were popular.

However, in order to do this practically I'd have to credit myself and/or the learning resources I made via a link at the end of my answer. The answer itself would be fully independent, including uploading my notation and diagrams to SE. But this way if someone stumbles upon my answer(s) and likes what they see I can at least get credit and thus justify spending some time on this SE forum, although to be truthful it's mostly for fun!

So I wanted to ask which, if any, of the following are appropriate credit links:

1) A very short link at the end of a complete answer with author's website.
2) A link whenever I use (with permission) graphics or learning resources from my primary website in the illustration of an example.

I'm asking because I was hoping to think of a fair way to get credit for my answers without being flagged or edited.

What do you guys think?

Grey

Comment: As long as your affiliation is disclosed and the answer is relevant (i.e., something you would have otherwised posted) there shouldn't be a problem with a "natural" link.  For example, `Here's an explanatory image from [my website](link goes here):`.  Linking the website when it's not directly related to the answer would be discouraged, but a lot of people will make a blog post talking about the question/answer and then come back and reference the blog in the post here.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the SE line on this is as follows:

If you are including images or other resources from an external site, it is entirely appropriate to include a footnote or citation with a link back to that material. For formatting purposes, I suggest using superscript callouts <sup>1</sup> in the body (done with `<sup>1</sup>` in markdown's HTML subset).

---

<sup>1</sup> Then put citations like so below a horizontal rule `----------`.

For regular author attribution, you should *not* include links or signatures in the body of your post. Every one of your posts already has your name next to it, which is a link to your profile page. You *should* put any attribution links you wish into your bio.

The one accepted "workaround" to this would be changing your display username to include the name of your site. It won't be hyperlinked (except to your profile page) but you can still communicate "Dave - Davesmusic.com" for example.

Comment: As well, you can relicense the content you post here, as [is widely done on TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/relicensing-code-from-answers), however, with the intention to choose a better free license than CC.